# Unspecified error could not find a writer

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to run and check a sample program from [here](https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico) and executing its [sample.c](https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico/blob/master/rnt/sample/sample.c). I am giving its argument, first is the path to facefinder, second is input image, third is output image and so on. But when i give all the paths, it show me following error and close. I am using Visual studio 2015 and opencv 2.4.10

Error:

[image]

Command line argument

[image]

Paths

```
// command line options
        printf("Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.\n");
        printf("  -i,  --input=PATH          set the path to the input image\n");
        printf("                               (*.jpg, *.png, etc.)\n");
        printf("  -o,  --output=PATH         set the path to the output image\n");
        printf("                               (*.jpg, *.png, etc.)\n");
        printf("  -m,  --minsize=SIZE        sets the minimum size (in pixels) of an\n");
        printf("                               object (default is 128)\n");
        printf("  -M,  --maxsize=SIZE        sets the maximum size (in pixels) of an\n");
        printf("                               object (default is 1024)\n");
        printf("  -a,  --angle=ANGLE         cascade rotation angle:\n");
        printf("                               0.0 is 0 radians and 1.0 is 2*pi radians\n");
        printf("                               (default is 0.0)\n");
        printf("  -q,  --qthreshold=THRESH   detection quality threshold (>=0.0):\n");
        printf("                               all detections with estimated quality\n");
        printf("                               below this threshold will be discarded\n");
        printf("                               (default is 5.0)\n");
        printf("  -c,  --scalefactor=SCALE   how much to rescale the window during the\n");
        printf("                               multiscale detection process (default is 1.1)\n");
        printf("  -t,  --stridefactor=STRIDE how much to move the window between neighboring\n");
        printf("                               detections (default is 0.1, i.e., 10%%)\n");
        printf("  -u,  --usepyr              turns on the coarse image pyramid support\n");
        printf("  -n,  --noclustering        turns off detection clustering\n");
        printf("  -v,  --verbose             print details of the detection process\n");
        printf("                               to `stdout`\n");

        //
        printf("Exit status:\n");
        printf(" 0 if OK,\n");
        printf(" 1 if trouble (e.g., invalid path to input image).\n");
```

my overall argument

```
E:\\pico-master\\rnt\\cascades\\facefinder -i E:\\1.jpg -o E:\\ -m 128 -M 1024 -a 0.0 -q 5.0 -c 1.1 -t 0.1
```

Comment: Can you please show your `-o` output path? It seems that you're giving an invalid image extension.

Comment: i update the question

Comment: You should specify an output image: "-o E:\\img.jpg" etc...

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you post it as a answer so we can sort it out. and how i can convert it to webcam input as command line argument

Comment: I can't now, I'll post it tomorrow. Can you explain better your second sentence please?

Comment: My second phase is like now i am taking image as an input by giving path of a image, now instead of giving path of a image i want it to perform operation through my webcam, how i can pass that through it

Comment: I added an answer. I cannot check if this works with your webcam, but it should. Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV *could not find a writer* to write the image to disk because you didn't specify an image path in the `-o` option.

Use `-o path_to_image` to save the output image, e.g.:

```
-o E:\\img.jpg
```

Comment: but it should be 0 or 1, like we have cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 )

Comment: No, your sample uses hardcoded 0. If you need to be able to select also the device number, you have to slightly modify the program. But that's material for another question

Comment: yes but when i used hardcoded 0 it give me error of invalid argument, even after removing -i

Comment: well, this answers the question. You can ask a new question on how to set the camera device.

Comment: I open new thread for camera device here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300914/how-to-give-argument-for-webcam