# How to give argument for webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using command line argument and by question is related to my last question as i want to check it through webcam but when i give command line argument regarding camera operation (0), 
[image]
it give me error on it as `invalid argument 0`. 
[image]
This my explained last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215202/unspecified-error-could-not-find-a-writer) but in that question i am using image path, but now i want to open webcam functionality for testing. This is the [Sample Program](https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico/blob/master/rnt/sample/sample.c) i am using for testing and checking result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use default camera, you need to **not** pass `-i` argument.

This command line works for me:

```
path\\to\\cascade\\facefinder -m 128 -M 1024 -a 0.0 -q 5.0 -c 1.1 -t 0.1
```

All but first arguments are optional.